# Split JSON file created from createWriteStream into multiple JSON files in Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I have this node script which writes a large object to a JSON file using fs.createWriteStream

```
 const stream = fs.createWriteStream("delimit.json");
  stream.once("open", fd => {
    for (let object in finalJson) { //finalJSON is the object
      stream.write(
        '{ "index" : { "_id" : "' + finalJson[object]["PID Number"] + '" } }\n'
      );
      stream.write(JSON.stringify(finalJson[object]) + "\n");
    }
    stream.end();
 });
```

Is there any way to split the created JSON file into 10mb JSON files?
Thanks

Comment: Wrap your code into for loop...